# port been allowed and opened in ubuntu server but while checked in check port its seems closed

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, nginx

I have used ufw  to open 5055,8082  and 5013 port. It shows 
Status: active

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8082                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5013                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5055                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5013/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5013/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5055/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5055/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2021                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8082 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5013 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5055 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5013/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5013/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5055/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5055/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2021 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

but while checking the port from external it seems closed .. any help and suggestion would be very helpful ... Thank you !

Comment: How were you checking the port from the outside ?  `nmap` ?

Answer (score 2):

Open network port means there is an application/process accepting connections on that port. The output of `ufw` you've provided only means that firewall won't intervene when something tries to connect to that port,it doesn't mean the port is automatically open. Opening the port is responsibility of an application.

Consider these two examples:

```
$ nmap -p 5566 localhost 
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-10 15:06 CST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5566/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.22 seconds
```

Now if I start an application on it `nc -l 5588`

```
$ nmap -p 8866 localhost 
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-10 15:07 CST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5566/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.18 seconds
```

See also [Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_port).